# JPA, Wildfly 14 and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly

I'm trying to connect to my PostgreSQL DB with JPA and wildfly 14 as webserver. I followed several tutorials, but I always get:

> Can't find a persistence unit named 'test'

What I did:

download postgresql-42.2.5.jar and copy it in "wildfly-14.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\postgres\main\"
module.xml in the same dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
        <!-- Make sure this matches the name of the JAR you are installing -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

then modified the standallone-full.xml

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/test" pool-name="test" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</connection-url>
  <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
  <driver>postgres</driver>
  <security>
      <user-name>postgres</user-name>
      <password>8a6rbd7a5c3a3fsavf4rq</password>
  </security>
```

and

```
<driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

now the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1"
                 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/test</jta-data-source>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </properties>    
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

after that, of course, a bit java:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
private EntityManager em;
```

So, that's all I did - but tried more...
In the deployment came the error:

> WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'test' in deployment ...

I have no idea what to do. Did I forgot some maven dependencies?

Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` in `module.xml` has to match the path. (without main)

Change it to `<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgres">`

EDIT:

Also the recommended place to put your modules is directly into $JBOSS_HOME\modules

So in your case: `$JBOSS_HOME\modules\org\postgres\main\`

Comment: This and "META_INF" was it. -.-
Thanks and have a nice day!